# Custom installer for Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, installation, google-chrome-extension, customization, chromium

I would like to provide an installation of Chrome (or probably Chromium?) that comes pre-installed with my extension, installed to a separate folder and has the `--enable-experimental-extension-apis` turned-on by default. Would also be cool to be able to customize the looks and feels to be more suitable for my brand.

Does anyone know if its allowed by Google's TOS? Is it possible? Was it done before? Is there any easy way to do that, without hacking around on Chromium source code?

Comment: What operating systems do you need this to work on?  Can you expect any scripting languages to be installed, e.g., Python?

Comment: Mostly Windows, and no. I can install that as part of a custom installer tho. What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know enough C to modify some code, [mini_installer](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/installer/mini_installer/) is a good place to start.  This is what people would be downloading anyway, so tweaking some of the code there to suit your needs would be the best bet.  Install it where you like, make whatever changes before/after the install, etc.

Otherwise, you could write some kind of script that downloads and runs the installer, and then changes settings.  For compatibility with your apparent target audience, a simple batch script would be the best bet.

Another option is [Chromium Portable](http://crportable.sourceforge.net/).  You make any changes you like, and upload a zip file.  All they have to do is download and unzip it.  Most users can manage that, but pictures on the download page don't hurt.  You could also write a small program or script to download the zip file, unzip it, and run anything that needs to be run (or Chromium it self).

Comment: I already thought of the portable option after posting this question here, but pointing me to mini_installer is pretty useful too. I think I'll go with a modified portable version and an installer that unzips it and adds some desktop/start-menu shortcuts, as it requires less work on my side when new Chromium versions are out. I'm afraid my bounty has already expired.. but I'll start a new one and award it in a couple hours when stackoverflow lets me. Thanks!

Comment: **deleted** (had some issue with awarding it - never mind. I thought I didn't have to wait, but it seems like I do)

Answer (score 2):

It's technically possible and allowed. Indeed, there are a number of forks of Chromium, such as [Iron](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron.php) and [Comodo Dragon](http://www.comodo.com/home/browsers-toolbars/browser.php).

Whether it's a good idea is another question entirely. Unless you're prepared to maintain your fork on a long-term basis (and in particular, to provide software updates to your users on a frequent basis), it's probably not a good idea. You'd probably do better to instruct your users to install Google Chrome normally, then give them a link to install your extension.

As far as experimental extension APIs go, I'd avoid them. They may be removed or changed significantly in future versions of Chrome. If you must use them, just instruct the user on how to enable them.

Comment: That's why I asked if it requires hacking around on Chromium's source, because if not (and it can be added as something external to the core codebase), I won't need to maintain a fork and updates should work as usual. As to experimental APIs... unfortunately, one of the core functionalities of the extension requires it (it is about to get non-experimental in the near future according to Google, but I don't want to delay the release until it does). Explaining to (mostly non tech-savvy) users how to enable it is a concern for me, and the main reason I'm trying to ship a custom Chromium installer

Comment: How about if you temporarily ship a script which enables the appropriate flags for users, then? I'm not sure about all OSes, but on Mac OS X flags are stored in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Local State` (a JSON file), under `browser.enabled_labs_experiments`.

Comment: That could work too I guess... but is it really a good idea to enable experimental features on a browser they might be using for other things too? I assume it doesn't go through the full QA process at Google, and might screw up things (as they very clearly state in their `about:flags` page). Maybe I should create a separate profile for that? I'd really prefer to just give them an executable that'll simply add a  shortcut with a branded icon on their desktop that just works :-(